# mplayer audio desync

Tags: linux, audio, sync, mplayer

I have and avi file and an ac3 file that contains an alternate audio stream.
I run mplayer like:

```
mplayer -audiofile foo.ac3 bar.avi
```

mplayer takes the audio stream from the ac3 file as expected, but when I try to scroll the video using arrows or pgup/pgdown keys, the audio gets desynced: mplayer just starts playing the audio stream from the beginning.

Do I have to pass any additional command line arguments in order to make it scroll properly without desyncing audio?

Comment: My mplayer scrolls both video and external audiofile.

Comment: @Vi: what version are you using? Maybe I have an outdated one.

Comment: MPlayer UNKNOWN-4.3.2 (C) 2000-2009 MPlayer Team (built from SVN)
MPlayer SVN-r29142-4.3.3 (C) 2000-2009 MPlayer Team (Debian squeeze's, but not up to date).
Both are scrolling both audiofile and video.

Comment: Mine is more recent (r29390) and I get audio desynced.

Comment: May be it is because I'm testing not with that `ac3` format but with plain wav or mp3? Try to generate simpler sound `sox -n qqq.wav synth 440` and test with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to process your video through the `mencoder` which also supports `-audiofile` option. I hope the resulting file will be scrollable.

Comment: My goal is to be able to watch the video with an alternate audio stream without doing any processing.